# How to find a tabletop RPG group open to newbies in France?

Tags: new-players, finding-other-players

I would like to try out tabletop RPG games but don't know how to find a group.

Is there an usual way to find other players? Especially ones who would accept a complete newcomer to join ?

I tried basic internet search, Meetup and Facebook, with no result.

I live in France and can play in either French or English. Answers containing tips specific to the country and links to websites or social media groups in either language are welcome.

Comment: @Wibbs Thank you for the advice. I checked the links given by the (excellent) answer without success. I guess my options are posting flyers, or playing online. Is it ok to keep this question as it is for a few days? (In case there are resources better suited to find groups around my location)

Comment: The question of whether this country/region-specific question should be marked duplicate or not discussed on meta [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8492/23970).

Comment: Are you looking for a group for a specific RPG? Or any RPG in general?

Comment: @V2Blast Preferably Fantasy-themed, with short or medium-lenght campaigns, most importantly something relatively easy to get into

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Le dé à une face" was recommended by a fellow online player (I'm from Paris, so I wouldn't know), I found their address here:

https://www.gralon.net/mairies-france/haute-garonne/associations-tag-jeu-de-role-toulouse_30583_31555.htm

Also, [Les enfants de R'lyeh](https://www.les-enfants-de-rlyeh.fr/) regularly organize One-shots, they might be able to help as well.

There are a few others but they usually have some kind of long-term planning that makes newbies integration a bit tricky

Generally, you could use this "[annuaire des assos de jeu de rôle](http://www.le-thiase.fr/annuaire-associations-jdr/)" (directory), it's not always up to date but still could help

There are also a few online communities that could help find ressources or people to play IRL, the biggest one probably being [CasusNo](https://www.casusno.fr/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could search reddit's LFG forum for "France":
http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=france+site%3Awww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Flfg

The top result is from four months ago, from a DM in Paris looking for players:
https://www.reddit.com/r/lfg/comments/8p9c18/offlinelfp5eparis_franceenglish_or_francais/

The second result is from a year ago, directing players to a forum for coordination:
https://forum.opale-roliste.com

Answer (score 1):

The [Opale](http://forum.opale-roliste.com/) forums are one of the best ways to find groups or clubs looking for players and ready to welcome newbies. Bit of a warning though, it would seem that the roleplayer community in France is centered around a few major towns, especially Paris.

If you live in or near Paris, I can recommend the [Antre](http://www.antre.fr/forum/) association, one of the few active big structure left around Paris, as far as I'm aware. I'm playing there regularly. They have open events every second friday, anyone is welcome. You can get more information on the forums.

You can also try the [Centre Ludique de Boulogne-Billancourt](http://centreludique-bb.fr/jeux-de-role/ludotheque/jeux-de-role), also near Paris. They have a small but active roleplaying group there. There's a couple downside with them though: they don't have that much room to fit groups of players, and their adhesion fee is quite high.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about Opale-roliste. The author mentionned looking for games around Toulouse in a previous version of the question